# Ajax slider control not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, slider, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Ajax slider control in which if the user types numbers into the input element the slider is moving to the center exactly (that is what i need) and the maximum value must be double the value of the entered value and it is also working fine.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Slider1" EnableViewState="false" BoundControlID="Slider1_Boundcontrol"  Minimum="0" Maximum="10000" Steps="0">
</asp:SliderExtender>
<asp:TextBox ID="Slider1" runat="server" Width="30" ontextchanged="Slider1_TextChanged" EnableViewState="false" style="height: 22px" />
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="Slider1_Boundcontrol" runat="server" Width="30" EnableViewState="false"
 AutoPostBack="true"  />
<br />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and

```
protected void Slider1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int max = 0;
int entry = Convert.ToInt32(Slider1_Boundcontrol.Text);
if (entry>0)
{
max = entry * 2;
SliderExtender1.Maximum = max;
}
entry = 0;
max = 0;
}
```

But my problem here is first time when i enter 500 then the maximum value has to be 1000 it is working but the 2nd time when i enter above 1000(i.e max value) it is not working for example if i enter 1100 the slider moves to the center and the value in the textbox changes to 1000  and if i enter below 1000(i.e max value) it is working.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

When you bind the input field to the slider you can only enter a value that is inside the range of the slider, so the solution is simply to have an input field that is not bound to the slider.

Comment: :then how come the slider will move when i enter a value in the input field?

Comment: @bala3569: That's what the bound input field does.